# CSS issue on apex page message tag

Tags: visualforce

[image]

I have used the  tag to display this but i definately want the Text in a single line wide stretched .

Any CSS or Html or Vf guru if you have any hack will be helpful.Thanks

Comment: Might help if you post the html

Comment: sorry it comes directly from salesforce servers

Comment: Where is that validation error coming from? A validation rule or a validation in code ?

Comment: validation in code .I think its browser issue .This was in Chrome and looks good in IE and opera

Comment: If you want to home-brew it, try using this. pbErr is the styleclass that salesforce uses to display error messages <div class="pbError" >
        <apex:outputText styleClass="pbError" >
        This is an error
        </apex:outputText>
  </div>

Comment: You're displaying it using <apex:pageMessages> or similar? Can you experiment with escape="false" attribute to make sure the Apex code (or whatever is the source) doesn't contain any extra <br/> etc...

Answer (score 1):

Put the error text inside summary parameter. For eg -

apex:pageMessage severity="Error" strength="3" title="Error :" summary="You are not authorized to delete records. Please contact your system administrator.">/apex:pageMessage